# What is a mouse-drag in the context of `Win32::Console`?

Tags: perl, winapi, console, mouseevent

What would constitute a mouse-drag when using the `Input` method from [Win32::Console](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aConsole)?

```
use Win32::Console qw(STD_INPUT_HANDLE ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT);

my $con_in = Win32::Console->new(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
$con_in->Mode(ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT);

sub getch {
    my ( $arg ) = @_;
    my @event = $con_in->Input();
    my $event_type = shift( @event );
    if ( defined $event_type and $event_type == 2 ) { 
        my( $x, $x, $button_state, $control_key, $event_flags ) = @event; 

        my $button_drag = ?;

        return handle_mouse( $x, $y, $button_state, $button_drag, $arg );
    }
}
```

The `getch` on Linux looks like this:

```
sub getch {
    my ( $arg ) = @_;
    my $c = ReadKey 0;
    if ( $c eq "\e" ) { 
        my $c = ReadKey 0.10;
        # ...
        if ( $c eq '[' ) {
            my $c = ReadKey 0;
            # ...
            if ( $c eq 'M' ) {   
                # On button press, xterm sends CSI M C b C x C y (6 characters).
                my $event_type = ord( ReadKey 0 ) - 32;
                my $x = ord( ReadKey 0 ) - 32;
                my $y = ord( ReadKey 0 ) - 32;
                my $button_drag = ( $event_type & 0x20 ) >> 5;
                my $button_pressed;
                my $low3bits = $event_type & 0x03;
                if ( $low3bits == 0x03 ) {
                    $button_pressed = 0;
                } else {
                    if ( $event_type & 0x40 ) { 
                        $button_pressed = $low3bits + 4;
                    } else { 
                        $button_pressed = $low3bits + 1;
                    }
                }
                return handle_mouse( $x, $y, $button_pressed, $button_drag, $arg );
            }
            # ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, you really shouldn't do things like that to process mouse events. For nice mouse event handling, see the mouse support in Term::TermKey.

Comment: I have problems to install Term::TermKey on Windows.

Comment: Oh indeed; I simply meant you should use that on Linux, rather than that long nested ReadKey code.

Comment: Yes, I didn't manage to get install `pkg-conf` which is needed be by `ExtUtils::PkgConfig` which is needed by `Term::TermKey`.It's a pity because with `Term::TermKey` I could write Module which works for both OS (and `Win32::Console` has annoying bugs).

Comment: Actually I have planed - after I have something running for Windows - to replace `getch` with `Term::TermKey`.

Comment: Except that `libtermkey` won't work on Windows anyway. It's very much a UNIX library. It requires that the terminal work like it does on UNIX; that `read()` yields bytes, that these bytes are all representations of keypresses, that the terminal is either known by `unibilium` or `terminfo`, or that it is of a type known to use standard CSI notation - xterm or friends.

Comment: ... ofcourse, if you wish to help you could supply me some ideas on how `libtermkey` might be made to work on Windows as well. That might be interesting. ;)

Comment: I didn't see that `Term::TermKey` doesn't work on Window so I suppose I'm not an expert.

Answer (score 0):

I've found something, but I'm not sure whether it is right.

```
use Win32::Console qw(STD_INPUT_HANDLE ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT);

my $con_in = Win32::Console->new(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
$con_in->Mode(ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT);

sub getch {
    my ( $arg ) = @_;
    my @event = $con_in->Input();
    my $event_type = shift( @event );
    if ( defined $event_type and $event_type == 2 ) { 
        my( $x, $x, $button_state, $control_key, $event_flags ) = @event; 

        my $button_drag = 0;
        # MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE => 0x0001
        $button_drag = 1 if $event_flags & MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE; 
        return handle_mouse( $x, $y, $button_state, $button_drag, $arg );
    }
}
```